# Idempotent Message Retries in a Spring Boot Kafka Consumer with Batch Mode

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, batch-processing

I have a Spring Boot Kafka consumer that operates in batch mode. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "my-fancy-topic",
  batch = "true",
  containerFactory = "stringStringKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeEvent(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords) {
    myBusinessLogic(consumerRecords);
}
```

I've configured the error handler with `FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS`. This means that if my `myBusinessLogic()` throws an exception, the consumer will repeatedly attempt to consume the Kafka messages indefinitely.

My question concern to the behaviour when the consumer fails to handle a batch of messages, let's say Batch X contains 4 messages (A, B, C, D).
I would like to know if, during the next attempt, the consumer will try to reprocess the exact same messages (A, B, C, D), or if there's no guarantee of message identity in the retry.

If there isn't, how can I ensure that the retry processes the same set of messages (A, B, C, D)?
I have a use case where I need to ensure idempotency by having the same combination of messages inside a batch.

Comment: Are you committing offsets automatically? If not, it should retry based on the committed offset position, not based on the batch information

Comment: Yes offsets are committed automatically. In this case it will re-consume the same batch ?

Comment: It will resume from after the greatest committed offset of that batch. Batches aren't relevant though, Kafka always resumes from the committed offsets, if they exist. Otherwise, falls back to `auto.offset.reset` (default=latest) (end of the topic). Otherwise, you can manually `seek` your consumer to a mapping of TopicPartition to Offset values. https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html